# Django REST Framework: Transform value before validation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following model:

```
class Runner(Base):
    # ...
    progress = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=4
    )
```

I want that the user can enter 20 and the number is transformed to 0.20.
I've already done this in a form before by using the clean method.

```
def clean_progress(self):
    progress = self.cleaned_data.get('progress')
    if progress is not None:
        progress /= 100
    return progress
```

Does someone know how to do this in a REST API?
I've only found the validate_progress method but it's not working with this method because there is some validation before that gives me the error "Ensure that there are no more than 1 digits before the decimal point."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DRF calls `to_internal_value` to transform the encoded request data into python datatypes before handling the explicit validation on those python objects.  The error you are seeing is triggered in `DecimalField.to_internal_value`.

In my opinion, the cleanest way to handle this is to tell DRF what you expect the request data to look like, allow `serializers.DecimalField` to translate the request into python, then handle your transformation in the `validate_progress` method of the serializer.  Something like this (I'm guessing at your serializer name and base class):

```
class RunnerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    progress = serializers.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=2
    )
    ...
    def validate_progress(self, value):
        if not value:
            return value
        return value/100
```

NOTE: you could also make the decimal field more permissive at the serializer level, then round in the validate method.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I've solved it in another way now. I added a custom field because I also needed to change the `to_representation` method.